# Unable to Find Webpage Element Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to enter text into the "Search address or location" search field on this website - https://www.verizon.com/coverage-map/

It seems to be unable to locate the element however I've tried multiple variations for the XPATH and locating by other methods with no success. Below is the code snippet, also commented is the code i have working for another website with no issues.

```
driver.get("https://www.verizon.com/coverage-map/")
address_input3 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root_search_container']")))
# also tried address_input3 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search_input']")))"""
address_input3.clear()
address_input3.send_keys(address)
address_input3.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
driver.save_screenshot("Verizon.png")
time.sleep(5)


"""driver.get("https://www.att.com/maps/wireless-coverage.html")
address_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='searchLocation']")))
address_input.clear()
address_input.send_keys(address)
address_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
driver.save_screenshot("AT&T.png")
time.sleep(5)"""
```

HTML:

[image: Inspect]

Comment: Element is within an iframe. You need to switch to it before interacting with elements inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `IFRAME` which has wrapped the desired element. You need to first switch into the `IFRAME` and then perform any actions.

**Check the below working code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.verizon.com/coverage-map/")
driver.maximize_window()

# create WebDriverWait object
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# switch into iframe
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'gismaps')]")))

# Enter text into search box
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search_input']"))).send_keys("Your text here")

# Use below code to come out of IFRAME once all actions are performed within that IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This website is programmed to detect regular `selenium`, and block you from performing a regular search once you're inside the iframe. You'll need to use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) UC Mode to do your search.

After `pip install seleniumbase`, run the following with `python`. (It adds a breakpoint at the end so that you can continue writing your script from there.)

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.verizon.com/coverage-map/")
    sb.switch_to_frame('iframe[src*="https://gismaps.verizon.com"]')
    sb.type("input#search_input", "vermont")
    sb.click('li:contains("Vermont,  United States")')
    sb.click('a[title="Vermont, United States"]')
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```